# How to insert one file into another file's marked place

Tags: xml, awk, sed, text-processing

Target and source files are both xml type files.

I have a hard time using `sed` because it does not work well with special characters and those xmls are full of them.

I researched that there's a way of doing it with `awk` and here's my problem because I have a really hard time using `awk`

Edit:

Main xml file with marked position:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ip>
<?processing instructions?>
<lista>

<!--> EKOLOGIA +5 <-->
<kategoria nazwa="EKO" thumb="/home/xvision/ip/swf/EKO/eko.png">
</kategoria>
<!-- KONIEC PAKIETU <-->

<!--temp-->
</lista>
</ip>
```

File that's intended to be included in main file (second xml):

```
<!--> PAKIET FUN 50 GIER <-->
<kategoria nazwa="EDU" thumb="/home/xvision/ip/swf/EDU/edu.png">
</kategoria>
```

Final file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ip>
<?processing instructions?>
<lista>

<!--> EKOLOGIA +5 <-->
<kategoria nazwa="EKO" thumb="/home/xvision/ip/swf/EKO/eko.png">
</kategoria>
<!-- KONIEC PAKIETU <-->

<!--> PAKIET FUN 50 GIER <-->
<kategoria nazwa="EDU" thumb="/home/xvision/ip/swf/EDU/edu.png">
</kategoria>
</lista>
</ip>
```

Comment: Generally, it's a bad idea to use `sed` or `awk` for editing XML files. Use an XSLT processor instead, like `xsltproc`. Creating a stylesheet that includes the files in the right places with the `document('')` function.

Comment: @zx485 can I include that is bash/sh script?

Comment: @zx485 I find ```xsltproc``` to be a elegant solution but I still would prefer the solution to be in ```awk``` or ```sed``` because I'm still learning them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

```
$ sed -i -e '/<!--temp-->/{r file.insert' -e 'd}' file.main
```

insert the file at the marker and delete the marker line, inplace replacement modifies the main file.

`-e` option defines a scripts and can we used multiple times, here it's used twice for two separate actions, match line insert file and the second block removes the (matched) line. Pay attention to single quotes which are the boundaries of the script(s).

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU sed for that syntax of `-i` (BSD sed also has `-i` but that's not the syntax to use it as it requires a backup file name).

Comment: Oh wow this does everything! Thank you so much! Finally a workaround with ```sed``` to escape special characters. Could you please explain how this: ```{r file.insert' -e 'd}``` works?

Answer (score 1):

In case no-one can come up with a solution for you using an XML-aware tool, this might be all you need:

```
$ awk '
    NR==FNR { lines = (NR>1 ? lines ORS : "") $0; next }
    $0 == "<!--temp-->" { $0 = lines }
    { print }
' second.xml main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ip>
<?processing instructions?>
<lista>

<!--> EKOLOGIA +5 <-->
<kategoria nazwa="EKO" thumb="/home/xvision/ip/swf/EKO/eko.png">
</kategoria>
<!-- KONIEC PAKIETU <-->

<!--> PAKIET FUN 50 GIER <-->
<kategoria nazwa="EDU" thumb="/home/xvision/ip/swf/EDU/edu.png">
</kategoria>
</lista>
</ip>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I double checked and now redirection works so this does the thing